# How to allow ActiveX creating in WebBrowser control

Tags: activex, webbrowser-control

I have WebBrowser control in my .NET program. It actually doesn't matter which .net wrapper is used (wpf or winforms) because they all wrap ActiveX component "Microsoft Internet Controls" (ieframe.dll).

So I load some html/js code into the WebBrowser. This code tries to create some ActiveX and fails. Exactly the same code works fine when it's loaded into full IE. But in WebBrowser fails: new ActiveXObject("myprogid") throws "Automation server can't create object".

Does WebBrowser control have some ability to allow creating of ActiveX'es?

UPDATE: I added "

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

" 
at the top of html which is loaded into WebBrowser. It doesn't help.

Comment: have you ever solved this issue? I´m having the exact same problem!! Regards.

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution for the problem. But I used a workaround: I created ActiveX in .net host (where the WebBrowser lives) and made it available to JS-code inside the WebBrowser.

Comment: Could you please give details, including code examples, for your workaround? I´m having a similar problem! Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround on WPF.
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=system.windows.forms"
    >
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
        </WebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public void Run(Uri uri)
{
    m_gateway = new HostGateway
                {
                    MyComponent = SomeNativeLib.SomeNativeComponent
                };

    webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = m_gateway;

    webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
    webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class HostGateway
{
    public SomeNativeLib.SomeNativeComponent MyComponent {get;set;}
}
```

And we'll need to add the native lib as reference:

```
<Reference Include="SomeNativeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\References\SomeNativeLib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Then in our client js code we'll have to access to the HostGateway instance via window.external:

```
window.external.MyComponent.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem recently and my workaround (which does not require any additional references) is to just have a javascript function named ActiveXObject and a C# function that calls Activator.CreateInstance, a very simple illustration:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ComVisible(true)]
public class TestForm :
    Form {

    public Object newActiveXObject(String progId) {
        return(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId)));
    }

    public TestForm() {
        Controls.Add(
            new WebBrowser() {
                ObjectForScripting = this,
                DocumentText =
                    "<script>" +
                    "function ActiveXObject(progId) { return(window.external.newActiveXObject(progId)); }" +
                    "document.write('<pre>' + new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').exec('cmd /c help').stdOut.readAll() + '</pre>');" +
                    "</script>",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            }
        );
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new TestForm());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!. I was looking for something more or less exactly like this. I love the simplicity of HTAs and i use them to do small applications for my self or family. But on Windows 11 they will be crippled, imo mostly from not being able to launch seperate IEBrowser (iexplorer.exe) instance. So i'm looking into creating a WinForms app that behaves like a runtime environment for a custom html file, much like the current mshta.exe. This will be intereseting to test out.

Comment: @JakobSternberg You're assuming that HTAs require iexplore.exe. They do not. They use MSHTML. Removing IE does not remove MSHTML. Your HTAs will continue to work in Windows 11. And even if you have a script that depends on IE (via COM) that will also continue to work because IE is still part of the OS. IE is only disabled as a general purpose browser.

Comment: Yea, i knew that MSHTA.exe never required iexplore, but iexplore is usefull for several reason, and without it, my experience with HTA's would be crippled.. I tried an earlier beta version of win11 and IE via COM didn't work there. Now i'm in full version of win11, everything is still here, and there's no problems at all. :)